# Show that for the eigenvector, $u_i$ of eigenvalue $0$ of the matrix $A A^{\dagger}$, then $\langle u_i | Ax \rangle=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the eigenvector $\mathbf{u_i}$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i = 0$ for the matrix $AA^{\dagger}$, for an arbitrary $M \times N$ matrix $A$. Hence:

$$AA^{\dagger}\mathbf{u_i} = 0$$

Show that if $\mathbf{b}$ is in the range of A (i.e. $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$)

then:

$$\mathbf{u_i}^{\dagger} \mathbf{b} = 0$$

**My attempt:**

\begin{align}AA^\dagger \mathbf{u_i} &= 0 \\ 
\mathbf{u_i}^\dagger AA^\dagger &= 0 \tag{1} \\ 
\mathbf{u_i}^{\dagger} \mathbf{b} &= \mathbf{u_i}^\dagger A\mathbf{x} \tag{2}\end{align}

I am unsure how to link $(1)$ and $(2)$ because it is not given that A is unitary, so i cannot assume $A^{\dagger}A = I$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How are you finding eigenvalues if $A$ is an arbitrary $M\times N$ matrix? You need $A$ to be square.

Comment: The vector $\mathbf{u}_i$ is of size $N$ but the vector $\mathbf{b}$ is of size $M$, so $\mathbf{u}_i^{\dagger} \mathbf{b}$ is not defined for $M \neq N$. So you probably want $M = N$.

Comment: Hi so sorry! I have edited the question

Comment: Start with multiplying by $\mathbf u_i^\dagger$ to get $\mathbf u_i^\dagger AA^\dagger \mathbf u_i=0$ . Try to interpret the LHS as something familiar.

Comment: @A.Γ. Thanks for the reply! But we already know that since $AA^{\dagger}\mathbf{u_i} = 0$, $\mathbf{u_i ^{\dagger}}AA^{\dagger} = 0$. So even if I multiply $\mathbf{u_i}^{\dagger}$ on both sides, i would get $\mathbf u_i^\dagger AA^\dagger \mathbf u_i = (0)\mathbf{u_i} = 0$. How would this help?

Comment: @tzyyyy The LHS is $\mathbf u_i^\dagger AA^\dagger \mathbf u_i=\langle A^\dagger \mathbf u_i|A^\dagger \mathbf u_i\rangle$. Can you get more of that being zero?

Comment: @A.Γ. Hi! Can't believe I didn't see that. But can I confirm that since $\langle A^{\dagger} \mathbf{u_i} | A^{\dagger} \mathbf{u_i} \rangle = 0$, this implies that $A^{\dagger} \mathbf{u_i} = \mathbf{0}$ and hence, $\mathbf{u_i}^{\dagger} \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{u_i}^\dagger A\mathbf{x} =( A^{\dagger} \mathbf{u_i})^{\dagger} \mathbf{x}= \mathbf{0} \mathbf{x} = 0$?

Comment: @tzyyyy Right. Now you know how to deal with $A^\dagger A$ combination. It is quite standard argument.

Comment: @A.Γ. thanks so much man!